# All possible binary trees given only one traversal

Tags: tree, traversal

Given an inorder traversal only (or postorder/preorder only) traversal of a binary tree (not necessarily a BST), how does one code to generate all possible binary trees given this traversal?

I understand that the number of binary trees possible given 'n' nodes is (2^n)-n but if we have access to a single traversal of the tree, how can we code this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it recursively.

```
def emptyTree():
    return None

def node(l,d,r):
    return (l,d,r)

def singleton(x):
    return (emptyTree(),x,emptyTree())

def allBT(trav,length):
    if length == 0:
        return [emptyTree()]
    if length == 1:
        return [singleton(trav[0])]
    trees = [node(emptyTree(),trav[0],right) for right in allBT(trav[1:],length-1)]
    trees += [node(left,trav[i],right) for i in xrange(1,length-1) for left in allBT(trav[:i],i) for right in allBT(trav[i+1:],length-i-1)]
    trees += [node(left,trav[length-1],emptyTree()) for left in allBT(trav[:length-1],length-1)]
    return trees

def allBinaryTrees(trav):
    return allBT(trav,len(trav))
```

By the way, your number of binary trees is wrong. There is exactly one tree with 0 nodes and one with 1 node, there are 2 with two nodes. The recursion is

```
T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} T(i)*T(n-i-1)
```

since we can pick each item to be the root and can combine each possibility for the `i` nodes before with each possibility for the `n-i-1` nodes after. Thus `T(3) = 5, T(4) = 14, T(5) = 42, T(6) = 132, ...`

Comment: How is this formula incorrect? (2^n)-n. The numbers you have presented are all obtained by applying this formula.

Comment: Also, can you post the pseudo code? I don't quite understand how you did the generation of all possibilities.

Comment: The numbers don't agree with `2^n - n`, e.g. `14 = T(4) != 12 = 2^4 - 4`. They agree only for `n <= 3`. The code I posted is working Python code, I thought there was a higher chance a random SO user understands Python than Haskell. The main part works independently of the actual tree representation, one only needs to change `emptyTree(), node()` and `singleton()` to make it work with a real tree class. Would you prefer C-ish pseudocode?

Comment: Yes, sorry but I don't really understand python. A C-like code would be super helpful.

Comment: That's what I call luck. I just was about to type it up and then came [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720194/1011995). I hope it's good enough, if not I can flesh it out a bit.

Comment: Given 'n' nodes, how many binary trees can be constructed? How many BSTs can be constructed? I read that the number of binary trees that can be constructed is that Catalan number of 'n'. I also see the same answer for BSTs. How can that be possible since the number for BSTs should be lesser than the BTs?

Comment: Yes, Catalan it is. But note that that is the number of different **spines** of binary trees with _n_ nodes. It should be clear that the number of spines is the same for BSTs as for BTs, the difference is that given _n_ numbers and a BT-spine with _n_ nodes, there's only one way to populate the tree to get a BST, but there are _n!_ ways (if the numbers are distinct) to populate the tree disregarding order.

Comment: Ok, just so that I get it right. Given 'n' nodes, there are Catalan(n) number of spines of BTs(BSTs). The number of different BSTs will be Catalan(n) (Given 'n' distinct numbers). The number of different BTs (Given 'n' distinct numbers) will be (Catalan(n)*n!). This correct Daniel?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Node(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

function Tree(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
    let trees = [];
    if (start > end) trees.push(null);

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) { // consider 0 to end all as root node one by one.
        let leftTree = Tree(arr, start, i - 1); // find left subtrees possiblr for node i
        let rightTree = Tree(arr, i + 1, end); // find right subtrees possiblr for node i

        // make all combinations of leftTree and rightTree
        for (let j = 0; j < leftTree.length; j++)
            for (let k = 0; k < rightTree.length; k++) {
                // cretate result tree and push in result arr.
                let root = new Node(arr[i]);
                root.left = leftTree[j];
                root.right = rightTree[k];
                trees.push(root);
            }
    }
    return trees;
}

let result = Tree([4, 5, 7]);

console.log(result);

//Output
// 4 5 7
// 4 7 5
// 5 4 7
// 7 4 5
// 7 5 4
```